Vertical Circular motion - What's wrong with this approach?

Suppose a rod attached with a pivot at one of it's end and that it is hanging vertically somewhere on our planet. It has two tiny blocks each of mass m attached to it such that the first block is at other end of the rod and the second block is halfway between the pivot and the first block (this means that we can consider distance between two blocks as $l$ and the distance between the block in middle and pivot also as $l$), other parts of rod are massless. There is no frictional force acting on the rod. Some speed $u$ is provided to the block at rod's end horizontally, towards right such that after turning exactly $180$ degrees the velocity of rod will be zero ($v$(final velocity) = $0$).  I considered the block at the rod's end as the system. Applying work energy theorem on the system , total work done on block gives change in kinetic energy.
So,
$$ W_g + W_t = K_f - K_i $$
Work done by tension  = 0 (since it is acting perpendicular to block)
$$ -4mgl = \frac {mv^2}{2} - \frac {mu^2}{2}$$
($v$ = $0$ as stated above. ) So,
$$ u = \sqrt {8gl}$$
But the actual answer is $ \sqrt {\frac {48gl}5}$

Obtained by also considering the middle block as system and then applying the work energy theorem to both blocks. So, again
$$ W_g + W_t = K_f - K_i $$
$$ -4mgl - 2mgl = 0 - \frac{mu^2}2 - \frac {m}2 \left( \frac {u^2}4 \right) $$
($0$ in the above equation comes since $v$ is $0$, so $ \frac {mv^2}2 $ will also be zero. Work done by tension is again zero since force is acting perpendicular to blocks)
I want to ask what is wrong in the first approach where I only consider the lower block as system and not the whole rod and apply the work energy theorem only to the system caring only about velocity and forces on system and not on surroundings? (Hope you can see the image provided, 1 and 2 represent initial and final state).
Edit - I have provided more information regarding the problem since this question was closed due to lack of information provided.

Probably Earth surface gravity is acting on the system. It also seems suspended, possibly at $l$/2. Likely the direction of u is horizontal. With so many guesses, any answer becomes a gamble.

It is clear from the question  title  "Vertical Circular Motion" that earth's gravity will act on it. From the image it can clearly be seen that the rod is rotatingfrom one of its end. However I apoligise for not mentioning that u is horizontal.  How will the above problem be solved ?

Is the rod in free fall before the velocity is provided? Or it has a pivot somewhere?

@nasu The rod is not in free fall. You can assume the pivot at the end which doesn't have mass m


Work done by tension = 0 (since it is acting perpendicular to block)

I assume you mean here that the tension in the rod is doing no work because it is acting in a direction that is perpendicular to the circular motion of the two particles.
This assumption is incorrect (or, at least is not true in general). In order to keep the two particles rotating at the same angular speed then the rod must exert a force at right angles to its length on both particles - basically it speeds one particle up and slows the other one down. Therefore the tension in the rod will do work on each particle.
It is clear that the rod must exert forces at right angles to its length because if you replaced the rod by a light string (which can only exert a force along its length) then it would not be possible to replicate this motion in which both particles rotate with the same angular speed.

You are yourself saying that "rod must exert force at right angles to its length on both particles". But because the very force is perpendicular, how can any work be done?  Even if one consider that work is done, how will the above problem be solved then?

The rod exerts a force at right angles to its own length - but this force is parallel to the direction of motion of each particle. Therefore it does work on each particle. Essentially this component of force accelerates or decelerates each particle.

Okay, how are you going to solve this problem numerically?

The correct answer is obtained by treating the two particles and the rod as a single system,. With this approach any forces exerted by the rod become internal forces and therefore do no work on the system as a whole because of Newton's Third Law. In other words the rod does equal and opposite amounts of work on each particle so if you consider the two particles and the rod as a single system, work done by the rod on the two particles nets to zero.

I understood it now, thanks

If the bar rotates around a pivot at the end without a mass, the problem is that you assume that only one mass has $\text{KE}$ in the initial state. This is not possible for a rigid bar. Both masses have some initial velocity, and so both have $\text{KE}$. If the bottom mass has velocity $u$, then the one in the middle must have $u/2$.
If the bottom mass is accelerated from 0 to u by an external force, the middle mass is accelerated by the tension in the bar.

I can understand that the mass in middle will have velocity u/2, no objection to it. I am saying that if we consider only the lower mass as our system , not the whole rod and then apply work energy theorem on our system, why is the answer different?

What I meant was that if one only considers the block at the rod's end as system and everything else as surrounding, and only apply the applying the work energy theorem on the system, and thus not considering the kinetic energy of the middle block and the forces acting on it, why does that make any difference? I was asking why choice of system is affecting the answer .  gandalf61 has already provided the solution, so I am currently not in confusion but if you have another explanation then please tell

You need to take the net work in the work-energy theorem. You need to include the work done by the bar on the body, not just the work of gravity.
